# npm run dev not creating index.html

Tags: sveltekit

I am very new to sveltekit and was just trying to build my first project using npm run build and then upload it to github pages. After some errors it finally built it, but there is no index.html in the dox folder. I tired searching online and found that the issue is solved by adding `config.kit.prerender.default = true`, but I am not sure how I would add that.
svelte.config.js

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'docs',
            assets: 'docs',
            strict: false
        }),
        paths: {
            base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : '/Cubesofcalm',
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

This is the repository of the svelte project I am working on (for learning purposes)
https://github.com/iraklidzaganishvili/Cubesofcalm/tree/main/game

Thank you

I tried adding

```js
prerender: {
  default: true
}
```

so the code would look like

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'docs',
            assets: 'docs',
            strict: false
        }),
        paths: {
            base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : '/Cubesofcalm',
        },
        prerender: {
            default: true
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

but it threw me an error:
error during build:

> Error: Unexpected option config.kit.prerender.default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just add a `+layout.js`/`.ts` in the `routes` directory and add it there:

```js
// src/routes/+layout.js
export const prerender = true;
```

(Maybe the option existed in older pre-v1 versions.)

For GitHub pages I would *highly* recommend reading [the dedicated section in the documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages) to make it actually work.

Also, pre-rendering is *not* a requirement. You can also just specify [a fallback](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#options-fallback) of `'404.html'` and let that handle all requests.