# sveltekit asks me to set config.kit.prerender.default to be true, also tells me that isn't valid config

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

During `npm run build` of a new Sveltekit application:

> error during build:
> Error: adapter-static requires `config.kit.prerender.default` to be `true` unless you set the `fallback: true` option to create a single-page app. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode for more information

Sure, will do:

```
const config = {
  ...

  kit: {
    prerender: {
      default: true,
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Sveltekit then says this in invalid:

```
Error: Unexpected option config.kit.prerender.default
```

The [prerender docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#prerender) do not mention a `default` key.

How can I make my Sveltekit app build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883384/npm-run-dev-not-creating-index-html

Comment: @H.B. Kind of related. Answer may apply, but I don't have a `layout.ts` but rather a `layout.svelte`

Comment: Those are two sides of the same coin. One defines the layout UI, one is for things like loading data and setting opions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `@sveltejs/adapter-static` to get a working solution.

```
npm i @sveltejs/adapter-static@latest
```

The message changes to:

```
  You have the following options:
    - set the `fallback` option — see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/single-page-apps#usage for more info.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to your root `+layout.js/.ts` or `+layout.server.js/.ts` file. This will try to prerender all pages.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to any `+server.js/ts` files that are not fetched by page `load` functions.

    - pass `strict: false` to `adapter-static` to ignore this error. Only do this if you are sure you don't need the routes in question in your final app, as they will be unavailable. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#strict for more info.

  If this doesn't help, you may need to use a different adapter. @sveltejs/adapter-static can only be used for sites that don't need a server for dynamic rendering, and can run on just a static file server.
  See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender for more details
```

Which are all valid config options.

As the final paragraph notes **another option may be to stop using `@sveltejs/adapter-static`** - as some routes (eg, oauth pages that need to check URL params) can't be rendered as static files.

Comment: As I noted in the other question, pre-rendering is not necessarily a requirement. It is possible to have dynamic routes that take URL parameters into account via the `fallback`.